# Need to populate a channel's videos onto Google Sheets using YouTube Data API v3

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been quite overwhelmed with all of this as I am completely new to working with APIs. I would like to populate a Google Sheet with a channel's videos so that I can always have its stats updated anytime I need while adding (or replacing the oldest) new videos to the list. I tried following a video guide and feel like I'm close but I'm having troubles.

NOTE: The playlistID I used below is for the Google Developers channel.

The video I watched showed an example where the videos being pulled were the top search results for a specific keyword. I would instead like to pull the last 50 videos from a specific channel.

The original code had the line:

```
var sr = YouTube.Search.list("snippet,id", { q: "guitars", maxResults: 50});
```

I changed that to:

```
var sr = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list("snippet,id", { playlistId: "UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw", maxResults: 50});
```

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
var srVidsOnly = sr.items.filter(function(res){ return res.resourceId.kind === "youtube#playlistItems"});
```

I tried going through [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/) and after many trial-and-error attempts, gave up. I'm not sure what this line is supposed to look like at all.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sr = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list("snippet,id", { playlistId: "UU_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw", maxResults: 50});

  var srVidsOnly = sr.items.filter(function(res){ return res.resourceId.kind === "youtube#playlistItems"});
  var modRes = srVidsOnly.map(function(v){ return [v.resourceId.videoId,v.snippet.title]; });

  var ids = modRes.map(function(res){return res[0]; }).join(",");
  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id: ids});
  var vidStats = stats.items.map(function(res){return [res.statistics.viewCount, res.statistics.likeCount]; });
  activeSheet.getRange(2, 1, modRes.length, modRes[0].length).setValues(modRes);
  activeSheet.getRange(2, 3, vidStats.length, vidStats[0].length).setValues(vidStats);
}
```

The error given is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "kind" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")
```

Removing kind from the fifth line, like this:

```
var srVidsOnly = sr.items.filter(function(res){ return res.resourceId === "youtube#playlistItems"});
```

gives the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 12, file "Code")
```

Following the initial video guide exactly worked (videos from search result). The sheet was formatted just as I wanted it. I just need videos from a specific channel rather than a search results.

Thanks

Comment: Please extend your code snippet for to see where that `srVidsOnly` gets used.

Comment: Thanks for that, had a mistake in there. I edited my post to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please modify as follows.

  - `res.resourceId.kind` to `res.kind`
  - `youtube#playlistItems` to `youtube#playlistItem`
  - `v.resourceId.videoId` to `v.snippet.resourceId.videoId`.

So when above modifications are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `myFunction()` in your script as follows.

From:

```
var srVidsOnly = sr.items.filter(function(res){ return res.resourceId.kind === "youtube#playlistItems"});
var modRes = srVidsOnly.map(function(v){ return [v.resourceId.videoId,v.snippet.title]; });
```

To:

```
var srVidsOnly = sr.items.filter(function(res){ return res.kind === "youtube#playlistItem"});
var modRes = srVidsOnly.map(function(v){ return [v.snippet.resourceId.videoId,v.snippet.title]});
```

#### Note:

- From your script, I understood that you are using Google Apps Script and Advanced Google Services.

#### References:

- [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems)
- [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.